# How do I escape command injection in node child_process?

Tags: node.js, shell, child-process

I'm adding arguments to `child_process.exec` command using string concatenation and they are ignored

```
var exec = require( "child_process" ).exec;

var cmd = exec( "grunt build --project="+application, {
        cwd: application
    },
    function( error, stdout, stderr ){});

cmd.stdout.pipe( process.stdout );
cmd.stderr.pipe( process.stderr );
```

Why is string concatenation a problem and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your grunt build task to see if there is anything wrong. There is nothing wrong in your code with string concatenation in child_process.exec

Answer (score 4):

Your code is vulnerable to [command injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection). It depends where's `application` coming from and you need to make sure it's not customizable by user.

Malicious code in your example would be

```
var application = '; rm -rf .'
```

but it wouldn't work since you're also trying to change the current directory via `pwd`.

The [general recommendation](https://blog.liftsecurity.io/2014/08/19/Avoid-Command-Injection-Node.js) is to be careful with `child_process.exec` and use `child_process.execFile` or `child_process.spawn` instead.